# differential_drive_controller publishing with wrong timestamps

Tags: ros, urdf, timestamp, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using the differential_drive_controller plugin in urdf of my robot:

```
  <!-- differential drive -->
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>100</updateRate>
        <leftJoint>right_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
        <rightJoint>left_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
        <wheelSeparation>1.2</wheelSeparation>
        <wheelDiameter>0.3</wheelDiameter>
        <torque>5</torque>
        <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
        <odometryTopic>stereo/odom</odometryTopic>
        <odometryFrame>stereoodom</odometryFrame>
        <robotBaseFrame>base_link4</robotBaseFrame>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Everything works fine, although its data topics are publishing with completely wrong timestamps (they're huge).

```
    header: 
  seq: 175517
  stamp: 
    secs: 1453724932
    nsecs: 329340743
  frame_id: stereoodom
child_frame_id: base_link4
```

How I'm using tf's this is being annoying. Can anyone help me on this? Please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224999/differential_drive_controller-publishing-with-wrong-timestamps/) by [aba92](https://answers.ros.org/users/21911/aba92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Everything works fine, although its data topics are publishing with completely wrong timestamps (they're huge).

> ```
> header:
> ```

```
  seq: 175517
  stamp: 
    secs: 1453724932
    nsecs: 329340743
```

The `stamp` looks fine to me.

Remember that it actually represents *seconds since epoch* (from [docs.ros.org/std_msgs/Header](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html)):

> Two-integer timestamp that is expressed as:

> - stamp.sec: seconds (stamp_secs) since epoch (in Python the variable is called 'secs')

- stamp.nsec: nanoseconds since stamp_secs (in Python the variable is called 'nsecs')

> time-handling sugar is provided by the client library

So in your case, `1453724932` is actually `Mon, 25 Jan 2016 12:28:52 GMT` and some nanoseconds (converted using [epochconverter.com](http://www.epochconverter.com/)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-09**:
Related: [Most recent transform in tf Tree](http://answers.ros.org/question/208510/most-recent-transform-in-tf-tree/).